# Is there a way to decode a ES256 encoded JWT with a root certificate but without a public key or a private key?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, in-app-purchase

I'm receiving JWT from Apple for In-App-Purchases and would like to verify them when I decode them.

I'm using ruby (with ruby on rails) so I do:

```rb
JWT.decode(params[:signedPayload], nil, true, { algorithm: 'ES256', root_certificates: root_certificates })
```

I get the root certificates from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority

- Apple Inc. Root
- Apple Computer, Inc. Root
- Apple Root CA - G2 Root
- Apple Root CA - G3 Root

And the payload is base64 encoded JWT, but decoded it looks something like:

```json
{
  "notificationType": "DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_PREF",
  "subtype": "UPGRADE",
  "notificationUUID": "386fe04a-7caf-40b1-91ca-a4e29f2d135f",
  "data": {
    "bundleId": "com.socializusapp",
    "bundleVersion": "73",
    "environment": "Sandbox",
    "signedTransactionInfo": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIng1Y...",
    "signedRenewalInfo": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsIng1Yy..."
  },
  "version": "2.0",
  "alg": "HS256"
}
```

How can I verify the payload is correct? I tried another private key I use for apple sign in but doesn't work

Maybe I don't need to verify and I can just decode the signed fields? But then how do I decode them?

Comment: Apple seems to have ample documentation for this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/responsebodyv2?changes=_7

Comment: Did you try base64 decoding the signed fields? As @dbugger says, apple has documentation for this at the link supplied

Comment: @dbugger Ok I can base64 decode the fields, but how do I verify it's coming from Apple?

Comment: @obiruby same question, how do I verify?